# Failing to integrate Redux-saga with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am trying to use **Redux-saga** for the first time, so I have the following sagas file:

backendAuth.js

```
import {all, call, fork, put, takeEvery} from "redux-saga/effects";
import {auth} from 'backend/backend';
import {
  SIGNIN_USER,
  SIGNOUT_USER,
  SIGNUP_USER
} from "constants/ActionTypes";
import {showAuthMessage, userSignInSuccess, userSignOutSuccess, userSignUpSuccess} from "actions/Auth";

const createUserWithUsernamePasswordRequest = async (username, password) =>
  await  auth.createUserWithUsernameAndPassword(username, password)
    .then(authUser => {
      console.log('authUser: '+authUser);
      return authUser;
    })
    .catch(error => error);

const signInUserWithUsernamePasswordRequest = async (username, password) =>
  await  auth.signInWithUsernameAndPassword(username, password)
    .then(authUser => authUser)
    .catch(error => error);

const signOutRequest = async () =>
  await  auth.signOut()
    .then(authUser => authUser)
    .catch(error => error);

function* createUserWithUsernamePassword({payload}) {
  const {username, email, password} = payload;
  try {
    const signUpUser = yield call(createUserWithUsernamePasswordRequest, username, email, password);
    if (signUpUser.message) {
      yield put(showAuthMessage(signUpUser.message));
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('user_id', signUpUser.user.uid);
      yield put(userSignUpSuccess(signUpUser.user.uid));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(showAuthMessage(error));
  }
}

function* signInUserWithUsernamePassword({payload}) {
  const {username, password} = payload;
  try {
    const signInUser = yield call(signInUserWithUsernamePasswordRequest, username, password);
    if (signInUser.message) {
      yield put(showAuthMessage(signInUser.message));
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('user_id', signInUser.user.uid);
      yield put(userSignInSuccess(signInUser.user.uid));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(showAuthMessage(error));
  }
}

function* signOut() {
  try {
    const signOutUser = yield call(signOutRequest);
    if (signOutUser === undefined) {
      localStorage.removeItem('user_id');
      yield put(userSignOutSuccess(signOutUser));
    } else {
      yield put(showAuthMessage(signOutUser.message));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(showAuthMessage(error));
  }
}

export function* createUserAccount() {
  yield takeEvery(SIGNUP_USER, createUserWithUsernamePassword);
}

export function* signInUser() {
  yield takeEvery(SIGNIN_USER, signInUserWithUsernamePassword);
}

export function* signOutUser() {
  yield takeEvery(SIGNOUT_USER, signOut);
}

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    fork(signInUser),
    fork(createUserAccount),
    fork(signOutUser)
  ]);
}
```

And this is the file where the asynchronous consult to an api is performed:
backend.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

const backendServer = 'http://localhost:8000/';

const signInEndpoint = backendServer + 'api/token_auth/';

const signInWithUsernameAndPassword = (username, password) => {
  axios.post(backendServer+"api/token_auth/", {
    username: username,
    password: password
  })
  .then(Response => {
    console.log('Response: '+Response)
    return Response;
  })
  .catch(Error => Error);
}

export const auth = {
  signInWithUsernameAndPassword: signInWithUsernameAndPassword
}
```

The ajax is well executed through **axios**, and the `console.log()` in `backend.js` is reached, but the `console.log()` in `backendAuth` is not, and I get the following error in the console:

`index.js:1375 Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

I believe the problem lies in the way I am defining the return of the value of the `then` in the ajax of `backend.js`, but I am pretty new to frontend development, so I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is a simple fix - you are using an explicit block for the body of your `signInWithUsernameAndPassword` arrow function, so you need to use an explicit `return`. Since you have no `return` statement that function returns `undefined` which is cascading to cause the overall issue.

The quick fix is just to update the function to:

```
const signInWithUsernameAndPassword = (username, password) => {
  return axios.post(backendServer+"api/token_auth/", {
    username: username,
    password: password
  })
  .then(Response => {
    console.log('Response: '+Response)
    return Response;
  })
  .catch(Error => Error);
}
```

Now to understand the final error you're seeing due at the moment: since `signInWithUsernameAndPassword` returns `undefined`, you eventually enter the `catch` block of `signInWithUsernamePassword` in `backendAuth.js` due to the type error of calling `undefined`.then in `signInUserWithUsernamePasswordRequest`. The error in that `catch` block is an `Error` instance, not a plain string. I'm assume you're then displaying the `error` that is passed to `showAuthError` somewhere in a react component tree, but an `Error` instance is not something that is valid to be rendered. You could try calling `toString()` on it first to display future errors instead of causing a rendering error.